# Stanford CoreNLP server using 12 threads, 6 clients calling it and yet sometime “Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted” error

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp

Stanford CoreNLP server is using 12 threads, I have 6 mono-threaded clients calling it and yet I sometime get the error message:

> Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'))

How is it possible? I thought it would be safe to run up to 12 clients simultaneously since the Stanford CoreNLP server is using 12 threads and my clients only use 1 thread each.

---

I launch the Stanford CoreNLP server using:

```
 java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9001 -timeout 50000
```

which starts the Stanford CoreNLP server with 12 threads as I have 12 CPU cores (and I can see that Stanford CoreNLP server mentions it will use 12 threads).

The code I used to call the Stanford CoreNLP server is:

```
import os
import json
from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
import time
import sys
nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:9001')
total_start_time = time.time()

for i in range(9999999):
    text = 'without the dataset the paper {0} is useless'.format(i)
    print('text: {0}'.format(text))
    start_time = time.time()
    output = nlp.annotate(text, properties={
        'annotators': 'ner',
        'outputFormat': 'json'
    })
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print('elapsed_time: {0:.4f} seconds'.format(elapsed_time))

print('total_start_time: {0:.4f} seconds'.format(time.time()-total_start_time))
```

The entire error stack is below. The script is called `parse_captions.py` and it has a few more lines of code that the code I gave above, so the line numbers don't match. Also, the text being parsed is different.

```
text: anniversary of the liquidation of the litzmanstadt ghetto in lodz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 181, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002660423E780>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9001): Max retries exceeded with url: /?properties=%7B%27annotators%27%3A+%27tokenize%2Cssplit%2Cpos%2Cdepparse%2Ctruecase%2Cparse%27%2C+%27outputFormat%27%3A+%27json%27%7D (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002660423E780>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse_captions.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "parse_captions.py", line 37, in main
    'outputFormat': 'json'
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pycorenlp\corenlp.py", line 29, in annotate
    }, data=data, headers={'Connection': 'close'})
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 116, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9001): Max retries exceeded with url: /?properties=%7B%27annotators%27%3A+%27tokenize%2Cssplit%2Cpos%2Cdepparse%2Ctruecase%2Cparse%27%2C+%27outputFormat%27%3A+%27json%27%7D (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002660423E780>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'))
```

I use Python 3.7.3 x64, Stanford CoreNLP version 3.9.2 (i.e., 2018-10-05) and Microsoft Windows 18.09 "Professional".

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that this may be a limitation of the way pycorenlp handles networking relative to how networking works on Windows.

https://help.socketlabs.com/docs/how-to-fix-error-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocolnetwork-addressport-is-normally-permitted

I don't know how pycorenlp operates, as it is not officially supported by Stanford NLP.
Perhaps it is opening a new connection for every query it sends.  That would quickly use up the available connections, especially if they hang around for 4 minutes once they are finished.

A similar thing happens if I use Stanford NLP's software on Windows 10, stanza, after about 14000 iterations:

```
from stanza.server.client import CoreNLPClient

with CoreNLPClient(annotators="tokenize", be_quiet=True, classpath='$CLASSPATH') as nlp:
    print("Hello world")
    for i in range(1000000):
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print(i)
        nlp.annotate("Unban mox opal")
```

```
11000
12000
13000
14000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

It seems like the discount solution for this problem would be to make one of the suggested registry changes to reduce the lifespan of a closed connection.  The workaround which involves more work on your part would be to send more text per request.  The fancy solution on our end would be to find some way to reuse the existing connections instead of opening & closing them repeatedly.  In stanza, for example, we use `requests.post` for each query.  Presumably opening a connection and keeping it over the course of multiple queries is possible and more efficient.  However, I can tell you that won't happen any time soon for stanza, and no one here has any experience working with pycorenlp.

In general you will get a faster response by posting issues on github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP or github.com/stanfordnlp/stanza